# Mysql test for values in either of 2 tables that are parent and child

Tags: mysql

MySQL question.

I have a contract and orders file. A standard parent and child - one to many relationship.
A  contract can have many orders. The common join field is c_contract_id = co_contract_id.

A contract has a c_type_code that qualified the contract and the orders also have a co_order_type_code.

I am building a general search that allows the user to select based on many fields.
The query that is giving me trouble is finding the contract_ids of those contracts that have a specific type_code in either the contract or contract_orders tables.

There are many fields int he tables that the user can search on. The relevant fields for my question are:

```
CREATE TABLE `ndx_contracts` (
  `c_contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_type_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_contract_id`),
  KEY `c_type_code` (`c_type_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1


CREATE TABLE `ndx_contract_orders` (
  `co_contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `co_contract_orderid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `co_order_type_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `co_data` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`co_contract_orderid`,`co_contractid`),
  KEY `co_order_type_code` (`co_order_type_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1


SELECT count(1)
FROM contracts
WHERE 
    c_type_code IN ('02')
        OR (
               (SELECT count(co_order_type_code) FROM contract_orders
                    WHERE
                        co_contract_id = c_contract_id
                        AND co_order_type_code IN ('02')
               ) > 0
           )
;
```

This query works but it is terribly slow. I have only about 40,000 contracts and each has about 4 order records and the search takes over 311 seconds to return 320 seconds rows.

I would do an outer join, but that would return many extra rows.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to count the distinct contract id, so this should do it for you.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_contract_id) AS `contract_id_count`
FROM ndx_contracts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ndx_contract_orders AS co
  ON c.c_contract_id = co.co_contract_id
WHERE c.c_type_code = ? OR co.co_order_type_code = ?
```

Note this will allow for cases with contracts with no orders. The `?` would obviously be substituted with whatever your search value is. If you want the actual order id's themselves, just remove the `COUNT()` function in the select.

Your primary key on `ndx_contract_orders` is actually a problem though.  To do this join, where you only lookup by the contract_id, you would need the field order of that primary index to be reversed in able to enable indexed lookups by contract_id only.  Alternatively, you could just add an additional index for `co_contract_id`. Honestly though if order id is an autoincrement, that field alone should probably be your primary key and the `co_contract_id` field should just have it's own index. There would be no need to force a unique index across both fields, as the primary key autoincrement on order_id would ensure uniqueness.

Comment: thank you, I got called away on a production problem. The reason I didn't want to do a distinct is that in the actual Select I am returning about 25 fields of the contract, and joining with customer and address tables to get other fields to return to the user.

Comment: Your second point of separating the primary keys did the job. I am now under a second. Thanks!!!